# Select fields that are not in selected fields - MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table contains songs. I want to select top 3 of the most favorite songs and 3 of randomly songs which are not in the first one in one query.

E.g:
[image: table of songs]
and expected output:

```
song 6, song 8, song 5 then *whatever song*,*whatever song*,*whatever song*
```

Here what I tried but not working:

```sql
SELECT a.`song_id`, a.`name`, a.liked, b.song_id 
FROM `song` AS a, 
(SELECT song_id FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3) as b 
WHERE a.song_id <> b.song_id LIMIT 3
```

```sql
SELECT
    a.`song_id`, a.`name`, a.liked, b.ids
FROM
    `song` AS a,
    (SELECT substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT song_id ORDER BY liked DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 3) as ids FROM song) as b
WHERE
    a.song_id not in(b.ids)
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.29, it isn't compatible with `LIMIT` in subquery or `WITH` clause.

Comment: Try with UNION and the judicious use of parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have MariaDB 10.3 installed at the moment but I've tried the syntax below on an older MySQL 4.1 and both return the same results.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3) UNION
(SELECT A.* FROM song A LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3) B ON A.song_id=B.song_id 
WHERE B.song_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)) S ORDER BY liked DESC;
```

Comment: Glad I could help @KienPham

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 CTE's with a LIMIT works in MariaDb 10.2 and MySql 8.0

The second CTE does it random, while not selecting those from the first CTE

```
 WITH TOP3SONGS AS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM song
   ORDER BY liked DESC
   LIMIT 3
 ),
 RANDOM3SONGS AS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM song
   WHERE song_id NOT IN (select song_id from TOP3SONGS)
   ORDER BY rand()
   LIMIT 3
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM TOP3SONGS
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *
 FROM RANDOM3SONGS;
```

And this works in MySql 5.6, so most likely also in MariaDb 10.1.29
(I don't have access to a 10.1 so can't verify)

This time a left join to the top3 is used.
And the order by puts the top3 above the random before the limit 6.

```
SELECT song.*
FROM song
LEFT JOIN 
(  SELECT song_id, liked 
   FROM song 
   ORDER BY liked DESC 
   LIMIT 3
) top3songs ON top3songs.song_id = song.song_id
ORDER BY top3songs.liked DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 6;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=401f69377cd85223e5173c147a294e50)*

Comment: Thank you! Is there any chance for lower MariaDB?

Comment: @KienPham Check update, but I can't test it on such an old version of MariaDb. But since it works for MySql 5.6, and MariaDb is a fork of MySql, it probably will.

Comment: Ok, I'll consider updating my DB if there is no way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @KienPham So have you tried that 2nd query?  I thought that [LIMIT was already in MariaDb 10.0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/limit/)

Comment: Your 2nd answer looks like @tcadidot0's. I'd tried `JOIN` before but not work, that's weird.

Comment: Maybe you had used an INNER JOIN then? I just figured that it could be done without a UNION.

Comment: Yes, `INNER JOIN` is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should split it to two, and union the results:
first query to select the top 3:

```
SELECT song_id FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3
```

second query to select random three, not including the above selected songs:

```
SELECT song_id FROM song WHERE song_id NOT IN (
   SELECT song_id FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

and all together now:

```
SELECT song_id FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3
UNOION
SELECT song_id FROM song WHERE song_id NOT IN (
   SELECT song_id FROM song ORDER BY liked DESC LIMIT 3
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: My mariadb doesn't support LIMIT in subquery :(

Comment: So why did you tag your question with the [tag:mysql] tag instead of `mariadb` and in the question's title as well?

Comment: @emix sorry, I've edited my question. I didn't think it's MariaDB problem